# How to handle the problem of publish Error VS 2019 for IIS hosting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting, publishing

I follow the instruction to Create publish But having Error Msg like Image Below.

=============

Error Message

=============

Publish has encountered an error.

Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

[image: Error Msg...]

Showing Copying Fail. Dont know how to handle this.

[image: Problem]

Please Help. Thx

Comment: Your options listed there look really light. I have close to 10 on my asp.net mvc project. What flavor project is this?

Comment: @RichK. just testing some template online. Im just started learning asp.net MVC

Comment: Don't use online templates yet, use the built in templates first. When you get more seasoned, then become daring and try out online templates. You will find out you next to never have to do this. My Project Properties (just a couple) look like: Application, Build, Web, Package/Publish Web, etc.

Comment: @RichK. Thx .. i now can publish by using own create one.